# Sendemail with text in one-line?

Tags: bash, email

I have a bash script and I want to be informed when it crashes.
I use this:

```
sendmail my@mail.com < customMessage.txt
```

Howerer, I just want to receive an email saying either "ok" or "error". Is this possible without extra txt file?

```
sendmail my@mail.com < "HI"
```

does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a  *here string*

```
sendmail my@mail.com <<< "HI"
```

or a *here document*

```
sendmail my@mail.com << EOF
Hi
EOF
```

or just a plain old pipe

```
echo "Hi" | sendmail my@mail.com
```